# Display specific number of decimal base on value on a form

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that display values btwn .000001 to 50,000.000000 in a text box control.

I would like to display **rounded number** according to a range of value in the control source properties. Is it possible?

I try this simple example:

```
IIf( [unit_weight]>=100, Round([unit_weight],1),[unit_weight])
```

and I did get the following message

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error you receive is because you're using a `,` to separate arguments in an expression, while you should be using the list separator, as defined in your locale settings.

You can change your list separator by going to the control panel, then Region, then Additional settings ... , then List separator.

The usual list separator in England and the US is a comma, if it's not a comma it's usually a semicolon

Note that in VBA and SQL, you always use a comma to separate arguments, while in expressions, it's dependent on your locale settings

Comment: I did use the expression builder to build this expression and the intellisence show Comma not semicolon. Did also check the region setting and  List separator show ","

Comment: Well, I'm at a loss how you got that error then, because the number of arguments is just not wrong. Perhaps because you're missing the `=` sign at the start, before the `IIF`? But I thought that returned another error.